# The Alps, Great Lakes Earth

Tags: climate, geography, geology

This is the Alps back home, cornering the Italian Peninsula and dominating the nations of Switzerland and Austria.  The tallest, Mont Blanc, stands 15,780 feet above sea level.

[image: Topographical map showing Italian Alps]

In this alternate scenario, the Alps range is the European equivalent of the Himalayas, the result of a subcontinent continuously crashing into the mainland continent.  The tallest peak is 18,510 feet above sea level--and still rising.

[image: Line north of Croatia running south of Romania]

Marked in dark brown is the alternate Alps.  Turkey is black because, in this alternate scenario, it doesn't physically exist.

With this alternate Alps, will the Balkan Peninsula have a monsoon climate, similar to India?

Comment: Seems pretty specific to me, can closers comment on the broadness?

Answer (score 3):

### No

As the Wind Current map below shows, wind currents do pass through that area but they arrive from the west not the East. Monsoons occur because wind currents carrying the clouds that carry rain get stopped by the mountain and drop the rain there. Thus while the Balkan Peninsula would not get monsoons (In fact the mountains would actually block rain and turn it into a desert) the lands above and to the west of the mountains would more likely get the monsoons.
[image: c]
Sorry for the legend blocking Europe and most of Asia, it was still the best quality wind current map I could find.